# Sorting is lost when I move to next page in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, asp.net-core

I'm new to using MVC. Sorting is not getting applied to the next page, I have no idea why. My code in the controller;-

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber)
    {
        ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            pageNumber = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }
        var idealist = from s in _context.Idea
                       select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            idealist = idealist.Where(s => s.ContributedBy.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                idealist = idealist.OrderByDescending(s => s.ContributedBy);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                idealist = idealist.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date);
                break;
            default:
                idealist = idealist.OrderBy(s => s.ContributedBy);
                break;
        }
        int pageSize = 5;
        return View(await PaginatedList<Idea>.CreateAsync(idealist.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
    }
```

in view I have

```
  <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]" asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]">Contributed by</a>
  <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["DateSortParm"]" asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]">Date</a>
```

I am using paginatedlist.cs and the following is the code at the end of view page of the index

```
 @{

  var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
  var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
  }

  <a asp-action="Index"
  asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
  asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
  asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
  class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
  Previous
  </a>
 <a asp-action="Index"
 asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
 asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
 asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
 class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
 Next
 </a>
```

the problem is in the action method or pagination. I followed Microsoft docs for instructions. [referred doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your `Index`,you have the code `@ViewData["CurrentSort"]`,but you lost it in your controller action.

You need to add it.

```
    //add this line
    ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
    ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
```